# API Post request with RobotFramework - Empty Param

Tags: api, rest, robotframework

I have the following POST request to configure in RobotFramework,
trouble is that the devs set up the request as presented in the screenshot.
This is a file id which you get from a file manager and download it.
My question is since there isn't any params, key, value like FileID etc.
What would be your best bet to send that request successfully via RobotFramework?
[screenshot][1]

The code that I have tried is:

````
Create Session  mysession url=${test_env}  verify=true
        &{body}=  Create Dictionary  id=d67b39a6-4ea9-497f-a653-5eb2da418d23
        &{header}=  Create Dictionary  Cache-Control=no-cache
        ${response}=  POST On Session  mysession /download  data=${body}  headers=${headers1}
        Status Should Be  OK  ${response}  #Check Status as OK```

Response I receive is Bad Request or Unsupported media


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGyHo.png
````

Comment: Could you provide more of your code? This doesn't give us enough information to see where the issue is.

Comment: @MatthewKing I have updated the description with the full request.
I would highlight the id=d67b39a6-4ea9-497f-a653-5eb2da418d23, id has been added by me since RF does not let me post it without a param. 
The description of the request says that i should include ["d67b39a6-4ea9-497f-a653-5eb2da418d23"] - exactly as pasted here in the body section which works in Postman like that.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the body with json key e.g. json=${body} instead of data=${body}

Comment: @MatthewKing yes, I have, the error that I get from the console is failed: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
I am pretty sure it relates to this line of my request:

``` ${json}=    Catenate    {["d67b39a6-4ea9-497f-a653-5eb2da418d23"]} ```